# can't get json return in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, json, return, codeigniter-2

I have a login page, that sends a ajax request to the server when someone tries to log in. The ajax, goes to the server, cause they get logged in I've been able to confirm. But the problem is it seems my jQuery isn't receiving the JSON.

The function in my controller is:

```
public function login(){
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    if((!!$this->input->post('email')) || (!!$this->input->post('password'))){
        $ret = $this->users_model->login($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'));
        echo json_encode(array('status' => "OK", 'msg' => 'Logged in!')); //also tried return
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'FAIL', "msg" => 'Invalid Email or Pass'));
    }
}
```

and the AJAX function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#login").ajaxForm(function(json) {
            alert(json);
        if(json.status == true) {
                alert(json.msg);
            //window.location = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
            } else {
                alert("Problem");
                $(".error_msg").html(json.msg);
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

if I alert the json variable, it's blank, and if I do json.msg it say undefined. So... what do I have to do to get this to give the callback, a json object, or an object of any kind? Please explain it so I understand the problem, not just how to fix it. Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Here's the form too:

```
<span class="error_msg"></span></br>

<form id="login" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/login" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Email: <input name="email" type="text"/></br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"></br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Also please show the `<form>` markup.

Comment: As an aside, your server returns json.status either OK or FAIL, but you're testing `json.status == true`, which will *always* be true.

Comment: Updated, please take a look.

Comment: Your `</br>` is not correct. Replace it with `<br />`

Comment: Doublecheck that `base_url()` ends with a slash.

Comment: I just changed it to == "OK", and still get undefined.

Comment: I already confirmed that.

Comment: Are you on `localhost`? Does the `base_url()` match the domain name of the page submitting the form?

Comment: Yes, on local host, if I view the page source, the action is action="http://localhost/CItest/users/login"

Comment: Oh it's fine, Ive helped people with this kind of thing too. :P I know how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think I understand.

Is this the plugin you are using? http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api

In that case, use `ajaxSubmit`, not `ajaxForm`.

Other examples online do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').submit(function() {
    $("#login").ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(json) {
            alert(json);
            if(json.status == true) {
                alert(json.msg);
                //window.location = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
            } else {
                alert("Problem");
                $(".error_msg").html(json.msg);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, let me attempt that. But same call back function?

Comment: Edited to reflect other examples online.

Comment: Almost working, now, when the page loads, it auto submits the form, resulting in a return of status: "fail" then when I submit the form, it goes to the php page. What do I need to do to counter this?

Comment: Edited again. Run ajaxSubmit when the form is submitted, then return false so the form doesn't submit like normal.

Comment: Okay, so, here's what's going on now, I think we're almost done. alert(json) gives me, {"status":"OK", "MSG":"Logged in!"} but json.status is still undefined. After that we should be done.

Comment: The problem is that `json` is a string, not an object. If it were an object, your alert would show "[Object object]". Hold on a min.

Comment: After your `alert(json);`, do this: `json = $.parseJSON(json);`

Comment: Perfect! But if Im doing echo json_encode(array()); in php shouldn't it be auto json encoded?

Comment: It is json encoded, but the browser sees `{"status":"OK", "MSG":"Logged in!"}` **entirely** wrapped in a string!

Comment: so json_encode() turns the array into a string to be parsed? Is there a way to send the actual JSON object?

Comment: Not over the wire. The http protocol doesn't know what json is.

Comment: I see! Last question now, I was previously using a different framework that my friend made, and on his, he had the controller return the JSON object, but on here, I have to echo it, do you have any idea while I must echo and not return it?

Comment: His controller is likely echoing the return value somewhere else in the codebase.

Comment: Haha and all this time I thought it was returning it to the ajaxform funtion. :P Just checked it and in the end, it does echo.